ASP.NET Core Web Api - Project starting with multiple URL's on the browser address bar
I am trying to enable secure communication for my ASP.NET Core Web API project. I did this by checking "Use SSL" checkbox after right-clicking the project and clicking on the properties tab.
This is my launchsettings.json file
{
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:31200/health",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ISRMServices.Auth": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31205/"
    }
    },
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31200/",
        "sslPort": 44399
      }
   }
}

Now when I am trying to run my application using IIS Express, on the browser address bar, I see 2 URL's:
https://localhost:44399/https://localhost:31200/health

Instead I would like it to be only https://localhost:44399 or https://localhost:44399/swagger.
How do I achieve this ?

If express is like standard IIS you could look into the URL ReWrite module to not only address this perhaps, but could even filter what is shown such as www.website.com/web/page/live.html could show up as www.website.com/live , filtering out the directory and extension makes it look cleaner and is a safer format.

Simply because "launchUrl": "http://localhost:31200/health", is invalid. Based on your description I think it should be changed to "launchUrl": "/",.

@LexLi - Can i leave it blank like "launchUrl": "", if i am changing to "launchUrl": "/", in the browser i am seeing two slashes https://localhost:44399// ?

After testing, if you would like it to be likehttps://localhost:44399 you can change the launchUrl configuration to "launchUrl": "",and you can refer to the following example:
{
  "$schema": http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json,
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": http://localhost:47808,
      "sslPort": 44313
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": http://localhost:5084,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": https://localhost:7293;http://localhost:5084,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}


If you want the url to render https://localhost:44399/swagger, you can set launchUrl to  "launchUrl": "swagger":

